# How to compare two strings in Sightly/HTL? (AEM 6.2)

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I have created a simple dropdown with two options Yes and No which return the values of "true" and "false" respectively.

```
<enableTool
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
class="cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide"
cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-target=".list-option-listfrom-showhide-target"
fieldLabel="Enable tooltip?"
name="./enableTool">
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <true
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Yes"
            value="true"/>
        <false
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="No"
            value="false"/>
    </items>
</enableTool>
```

I want to implement the following logic in sightly

```
if (value of the returned string is true)
{
Do something
}
```

For This is wrote the following sightly code

```
<div data-sly-test="${properties.enableTool == 'true'}"> Value is true</div>
```

when I run this "Value is true" is always printed irrespective of the fact whether the the value of propeties.enableTool is true or false.

please note that if I write `<div> ${properties.enableTool} </div>` , I see the values as true or false ,correctly, as per my selection.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see an issue with your code. It should work fine. To better debug, please add more code related to dialog and the HTL file.

Comment: I have created a field with the provided code and used the same sightly code to check the test condition and it is working fine for me, Sightly code I have used :

<div data-sly-test="${properties.enableTool == 'true'}"> Value is true</div>
<div data-sly-test="${properties.enableTool == 'false'}"> Value is false</div>

Comment: Like the two comments above, I dont see issues in your code, what version of AEM are you using? also, i suggest you use the HTL REPL for quick HTL testing: https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [HTL Conditional Ternary operator](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/expression-language.html#conditional-ternary-operator) is what you're looking for.

```
<p>${properties.enableTool ? "tool is enabled" : "tool is disabled"}</p>
```